# Change DevExpress gridview datasource

Tags: c#, datagridview, devexpress, datasource

I am going to get datasource of a gridview and then add some columns to it and again populate new datasource in that gridview.

I use this code:

```
    try
    {
        if (!dt.Columns.Contains("Message_ID"))
        {
            dt.Columns.Add("Message_ID", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("Message_Status", typeof(String));
            dt.Columns.Add("cost", typeof(long));
        }

        List<string> phonelist = new List<string>();

        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            phonelist.Add(dr["phone"].ToString().TrimEnd());
        }

        results = api.Send(Properties.Settings.Default.SMS_Number, phonelist, message, Kavenegar.SDK.Models.Enums.MessageType.AppMemory, DateTime.MinValue);

        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            dt.Rows[i]["Message_ID"] = 123;//results[i].ID;
            dt.Rows[i]["Message_Status"] = "fgh";//results[i].StatusText;
            dt.Rows[i]["cost"] =  123;//results[i].Cost;
        }

        gridecontrol.DataSource = null;
        gridecontrol.DataSource = dt;
        gridecontrol.RefreshDataSource();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
         System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }
}
```

But I have a problem, gridview doesn't refresh with new datasource. I tried it with a fresh gridview and it seems that my datasource works fine and new columns supplies in it. But if I have a datasource in gridview I can't supply it with new datasource, I do not get any errors or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to call the [gridView.PopulateColumns()](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_PopulateColumnstopic) method after you set the gridControl's DataSource.  This will force the grid to recreate columns in your View and thus the new data will be visible.

Comment: Thanks my fried ,I'll try it and let you know the results..thanks